# How to call other data from other module in a user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this data from a module in a user defined function:

```
#gardenA
a = .......
b = .......
def moduleA(a,b):
    (function inside here)
```

and the other module:

```
#gardenB
def moduleB():
    (function inside here)
```

how can I use only the data a from moduleA inside gardenA to be used again in moduleB from gardenB?
I know that we need to import gardenA inside gardenB first, but then how to get the data a?

Is it gardenA.moduleA.a?

Comment: The obvious answer would be `import moduleA`, and then using `moduleA.a`. Is this answer too obvious?

Comment: is it like moduleA.moduleA.a ?

Comment: Well the fact that you have a module and a function within that module sharing the same name is confusing; why would you include the name "module" in a function definition?

Comment: I edit the question first to make it easier

Comment: @Joehan: No, it's simply `moduleA.a`, as I wrote.

Comment: Ok, so after the edit, the comment from @Dolda2000 would be `gardenA.a`, but they were correct with the first incarnation of the question. There is no need to reference the function - `moduleA` (which is stil confusing a confusing name btw) - when you want to access a module-level variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#moduleA

a = 4
b = 5

def moduleA_fun(a, b):
      return a+b


#moduleB
import moduleA

def moduleB_fun()
    print(moduleA.a) #--->4
    print(moduleA.b) #---->5
#call above function
moduleB_fun()
```

I think now u more clear.

Comment: why is it the moduleB_fuc() need to be changed to moduleB_fun()?

Comment: @Joehan for exactly the reason I was saying in multiple comments - calling a function "module" something is just unnecessarily confusing. It is _not_ a module. So a marginally better name would be one that indicated that it's a _function_ originating from a different module.

Comment: ok I get it now...is it the same  if there is  c = .... and d = ...... just like in the moduleA for moduleB. How can I make it a  = c and d = b in the moduleB?

Comment: @joehan i changed name of function because of removing confusion between module and function.